# Using Jacoco with Pax-Exam

Tags: java, maven-plugin, apache-karaf, jacoco, pax

I'm currently working on an application built on the OSGi model. All the testing process of my application is made by using Pax-Exam which create a new JVM by using Karaf.

I tried to use Jacoco for my integration tests code coverage but it doesn't seem to work.
When I'm using it (with the maven plugin), the jacoco.exec file created is empty.

As Pax-Exam is creating a new JVM to do the tests through Karaf, I set a Pax-Exam option with the javaagent in order to use the exact same arg line for the new JVM which will do the tests. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

I already tried to use Jacoco without all the Pax-Exam/Karaf/OSGi part and it works well, but I don't know how to make it work with my OSGi bundles.

I hope that someone could help with that!

Comment: As you've had no answers for a while, try the pax guys, they are very helpful and responsive, the mailing list is general@lists.ops4j.org

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at how the felix guys achieved this for their code coverage. 
[Felix Jaas Sources](https://fisheye6.atlassian.com/browse/felix/trunk/jaas/pom.xml?r=1459658)

Comment: don't know about the integration of sonar :)